# LS solution with orthonormal matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares, orthonormal

Let $A\in{ \mathbb{R}_{m \times n} }$ matrix, and **orthonormal** matrix $ P\in{ \mathbb{R}_{m \times m}}$. 
Let $ \underline{b} \in \mathbb{R}_{m} $.

Can I say the following?

1. $\min||A\underline{x}-\underline{b}||_2^2 $ has **single solution** $\iff$ $\min||PA\underline{x}-\underline{b}||_2^2 $ has **single solution**?
2. $\min||A\underline{x}-\underline{b}||_2^2 = 0$ $\iff$ $\min||PA\underline{x}-\underline{b}||_2^2 = 0 $?

For both questions I got that $\min||PA\underline{x}-\underline{b}||_2^2 = \min ||A\underline{x} - P^T\underline{b}||_2^2$ but it doesn't seems to help very much...
I also tried to simplify the LS problem by 2-norm definition by writing $ (PA\underline{x}-\underline{b})^T(PA\underline{x}-\underline{b})$ but I can't see how it helps.

Comment: For starters, dimensions aren't right. Is $b\in\Bbb R^m$? Notice that if $\text{rank}(A)<m$, for certain choices of $\vec b$ there will be no solution, but by using $P$ you can effectively change $\vec b$ to a vector in the image of $A$.

Comment: Expand the last expression using the orthonormality of $P$...

Comment: @player100 thanks. I tried, but the main issue is that LS problem can have single solution even if it's singular (if it's columns are linearly independent), so I cant invert the matrix $PA$ or $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. A LS problem $\min_x\|Ax-b\|_2$ has a unique solution if and only if $A$ has full column rank. Premultiplying $A$ with an orthogonal matrix does not change its rank.
2. No. For example,
   $$
   \min_x\left\|\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}x-\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\|_2=0,
   $$
   but
   $$
   \min_x\left\|\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}x-\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\|_2
   =
   \min_x\left\|\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}x-\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\|_2=1\neq 0,
   $$